# var_dump() and print_r() display null in php

Tags: php, debug

I am trying to debug php and it would help me if I could display some variables.

When I add `var_dump($value)` and `print_r($value)` to functions.php they show Null.

When I add `var_dump($value)` and `print_r($value)` to a specific plugin's php-file (in where the $value I want to display is defined and set) I get nothing back, not even Null. I am new to this and never tried anything like this before.

I suspect that the variables in the plugin's php-file are not global and are not retrieved to `functions.php`.

The variable I want to view/retrive is `$sexQuery` in the file:
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rencontre/inc/rencontre_filter.php

I think the problem is that `$sexQuery` is inside a very long function:

```
function f_cron_on($cronBis=0) {
```

When I add `$testvariable1 = 26;` inside the function I get Null, but I do get int(26) when I add `$testvariable1 = 26;` outside the function (before or after) and `var_dump($testvariable1);` in functions.php. Maybe the function is not read?

The whole file
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rencontre/inc/rencontre_filter.php
is to large, but the function in question is:

```
function f_cron_on($cronBis=0) {
    // NETTOYAGE QUOTIDIEN
    global $wpdb; global $rencOpt; global $rencDiv; global $rencCustom;
    clearstatcache();
    $Loo = (!empty($rencOpt['lbl']['rencoo'])?$rencOpt['lbl']['rencoo']:'rencoo');
    $Lii = (!empty($rencOpt['lbl']['rencii'])?$rencOpt['lbl']['rencii']:'rencii');
    $mailPerline = (!empty($rencOpt['nbr']['mailUserPerLine'])?$rencOpt['nbr']['mailUserPerLine']:2) - 1;
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/rencontre_color.php');
    $bt0 = (!empty($rencCustom['mebt'])?$rencCustom['mebt']:$w3rencDef['mebt']);
    $bt1 = (!empty($rencCustom['mebo'])?$rencCustom['mebo']:$w3rencDef['mebo']);
    $oo = ''; $ii = '';
    if(function_exists('openssl_encrypt')) {
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $ii = base64_encode($iv);
    }
    $bn = get_bloginfo('name');
    $s1 = ""; // (synthese admin)
    $cm = 0; // compteur de mail
    if(!$cronBis) {
        // 1. Efface les _transient dans wp_option
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."options WHERE option_name like '\_transient\_namespace\_%' OR option_name like '\_transient\_timeout\_namespace\_%' ");
        // 2. Suppression fichiers anciens dans UPLOADS/PORTRAIT/LIBRE/ : > 2.9 jours
        if(!is_dir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/libre/')) @mkdir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/libre/');
        else {
            $tab = array(); $d = $rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/libre/';
            if($dh = opendir($d)) {
                while(($file = readdir($dh))!==false) { if($file!='.' && $file!='..') $tab[]=$d.$file; }
                closedir($dh);
                if($tab!=array()) foreach($tab as $r) {
                    if(file_exists($r) && filemtime($r)<time()-248400) @unlink($r); // 69 heures
                }
            }
        }
        // 3. Supprime le cache portraits page d'accueil. Remise a jour a la premiere visite (fiches libre)
        renc_clear_cache_portrait(1);
        // 4. Suppression des utilisateur sans compte rencontre fini
        $t = (!empty($rencOpt['nbr']['delNotConfirmed'])?intval($rencOpt['nbr']['delNotConfirmed']):60); // Hours
        $d = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"))-(3600*$t));
        if(!empty($rencOpt['fastreg'])) { // email not confirmed ?
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
                    U.ID, 
                    R.i_photo 
                FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                    ON R.user_id=U.ID
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->base_prefix."usermeta M 
                    ON M.user_id=U.ID
                WHERE 
                    (M.meta_key='rencontre_confirm_email' or R.i_sex='98')
                    and U.user_registered<'".$d."' 
                ");
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                if($r->i_photo) f_suppImgAll($r->ID);
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('user_id'=>$r->ID));
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users_profil', array('user_id'=>$r->ID));
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'usermeta', array('user_id'=>$r->ID));
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'users', array('ID'=>$r->ID));
            }
        }
        if(!empty($rencOpt['rol'])) { // Uniquement les comptes Rencontre non finis. Utiliseur maintenue
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                    R.user_id,
                    R.i_photo
                FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                    ON R.user_id=U.ID
                WHERE
                    (R.c_ip='' or R.i_sex='98')
                    and U.user_registered<'".$d."' ");
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                if($r->i_photo) RencontreWidget::suppImgAll($r->user_id,false);
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users_profil', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                if(empty($rencOpt['rolu'])) {
                    $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'usermeta', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                    $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'users', array('ID'=>$r->user_id));
                }
            }
        }
        else if(!is_multisite()) { // general case : rol unchecked
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                    U.ID
                FROM
                    ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                ON
                    U.ID=R.user_id
                WHERE
                    R.user_id IS NULL
                    or R.c_ip=''
                    or R.i_sex='98'");
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                $s = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT
                        ID
                    FROM
                        ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users
                    WHERE
                        ID='".$r->ID."' and
                        user_registered<'".$d."'
                    LIMIT 1");
                if($s && !user_can($s,'edit_posts')) {
                    $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'usermeta', array('user_id'=>$r->ID));
                    $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'users', array('ID'=>$r->ID));
                }
            }
        }
        // 5. Delete the users in rencontre and not in WP
        $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                R.user_id,
                R.i_photo
            FROM
                ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
            WHERE
                R.user_id NOT IN (SELECT U.ID FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U) ");
        if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
            if(!empty($r->user_id)) {
                if($r->i_photo) f_suppImgAll($r->user_id);
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users_profil', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
            }
        }
        // 6. Delete inactive users
        if(!empty($rencOpt['dead'])) {
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT R.user_id, R.i_photo, R.d_session
                FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                WHERE R.d_session<(NOW() - INTERVAL ".$rencOpt['dead']." YEAR)
                ");
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                if(!empty($r->user_id)) {
                    if($r->d_session && $r->d_session!='0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                        if($r->i_photo) f_suppImgAll($r->user_id);
                        $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                        $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users_profil', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                        if(empty($rencOpt['rol']) || empty($rencOpt['rolu'])) {
                            $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'usermeta', array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                            $wpdb->delete($wpdb->base_prefix.'users', array('ID'=>$r->user_id));
                        }
                    }
                    else $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('d_session'=>current_time("mysql")), array('user_id'=>$r->user_id));
                }
            }
        }
        // 7. Fastreg décoché en admin : recadrer les nouveaux membres en fastreg - cas particulier
        if(isset($rencOpt['fastreg']) && !$rencOpt['fastreg']) {
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT U.ID FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U, ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R WHERE R.user_id=U.ID and R.i_status=4 ");
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                $p = md5(mt_rand());
                $wpdb->update($wpdb->base_prefix.'users', array('user_pass'=>$p), array('ID'=>$r->ID)); // confirmation email par demande de nouveau password
                $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users', array('c_ip'=>'', 'i_status'=>0), array('user_id'=>$r->ID)); // procedure inscription 1 a 4
            }
        }
        // 8. Mail de relance (uniquement enregistrement classique)
        if(empty($rencOpt['fastreg'])) {
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                    U.ID,
                    U.user_login,
                    U.user_email,
                    U.user_registered
                FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                    ON R.user_id=U.ID
                WHERE
                    R.c_ip=''
                ");
            $o = '';
            if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
                if(function_exists('openssl_encrypt')) $oo = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($r->ID.'|'.$r->user_login.'|'.time(), 'AES-256-CBC', substr(AUTH_KEY,0,32), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
                $s = "<div style='text-align:left;margin:5px 5px 5px 10px;font-size:13px;font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica;'>".__('Hello','rencontre')." ".$r->user_login.","."\n";
                if(isset($rencCustom['relanc']) && isset($rencCustom['relancText']) && $rencCustom['relanc']) $s .= "<br />".nl2br(stripslashes($rencCustom['relancText']))."\n";
                else {
                    $s .= '<p>'.__('You registered on our website but you did not complete the procedure. You\'ll miss a date. That\'s too bad.','rencontre').'</p>';
                    $s .= '<p>'.__('Thus take two minutes to finish the registration. You should not be disappointed.','rencontre').'</p>';
                    $s .= '<p>'.__('Regards,','rencontre').'</p>';
                }
                $s .= '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars((empty($rencOpt['home'])?site_url():$rencOpt['home']).'?'.$Loo.'='.urlencode($oo).'&'.$Lii.'='.urlencode($ii)).'">'.__('Login','rencontre').'</a>';
                $s .= "</div>\n";
                $he = array();
                if(!empty($rencOpt['mailfo']) || !has_filter('wp_mail_content_type')) {
                    $he[] = 'From: '.$bn.' <'.$rencDiv['admin_email'].'>';
                    $he[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    $s = '<html><head><meta charset="windows-1252"></head><body>'.$s.'</body></html>';
                }
                @wp_mail($r->user_email, $bn." - ".__('Registration','rencontre'), $s, $he);
                ++$cm;
            }
        }
        // 9. Suppression fichiers anciens dans UPLOADS/SESSION/ et UPLOADS/TCHAT/ et des exports CSV UPLOADS/TMP
        if(!is_dir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/session/')) mkdir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/session/');
        else {
            $tab = array(); $d = $rencDiv['basedir'].'/session/';
            if($dh=opendir($d)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh))!==false) { if($file!='.' && $file!='..') $tab[] = $d.$file; }
                closedir($dh);
                if($tab!=array()) foreach($tab as $r){if(filemtime($r)<time()-1296000) @unlink($r);} // 15 jours
            }
        }
        if(!is_dir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/tchat/')) mkdir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/tchat/');
        else {
            $tab = array(); $d = $rencDiv['basedir'].'/tchat/';
            if($dh=opendir($d)) {
                while (($file = readdir($dh))!==false) { if($file!='.' && $file!='..') $tab[] = $d.$file; }
                closedir($dh);
                if($tab!=array()) foreach($tab as $r){if(filemtime($r)<time()-86400) @unlink($r);} // 24 heures
            }
        }
        if(is_dir($rencDiv['basedir'].'/tmp/')) {
            $a = array();
            if($h=opendir($rencDiv['basedir']."/tmp/")) {
                while (($file = readdir($h))!==false) {
                    $ext = explode('.',$file);
                    $ext = $ext[count($ext)-1];
                    if($ext=='csv' && $file!='.' && $file!='..' && strpos($file,"rencontre")!==false) $a[] = $rencDiv['basedir']."/tmp/".$file;
                }
                closedir($h);
            }
            // ************************
            if(is_array($a)) array_map('unlink', $a);
        }
        // 10. Sortie de prison
        $free = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")-(isset($rencOpt['prison'])?$rencOpt['prison']:7), date("Y")));
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_prison WHERE d_prison<'".$free."' ");
        // 11. anniversaire du jour
        if(!empty($rencOpt['mailanniv'])) {
            $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                    U.ID,
                    U.user_login,
                    U.user_email,
                    R.user_id 
                FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                    ON R.user_id=U.ID 
                WHERE 
                    R.d_naissance LIKE '%".current_time('m-d')."' 
                    ".(!empty($rencOpt['mailph'])?'and R.i_photo>0':'')."
                LIMIT ".floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.1)) );
            foreach($q as $r) {
                $s = "<div style='font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica;font-size:13px;text-align:left;margin:5px 5px 5px 10px;'>".__('Hello','rencontre')." ".$r->user_login.","."\n";
                if(!empty($rencOpt['textanniv']) && strlen($rencOpt['textanniv'])>10) $s .= "<br />".nl2br(stripslashes($rencOpt['textanniv']))."\n";
                else $s .= "<br />".__('Happy Birthday','rencontre')."&nbsp;".$r->user_login." !\n";
                $s .= "</div>\n";
                $he = array();
                if(!empty($rencOpt['mailfo']) || !has_filter('wp_mail_content_type')) {
                    $he[] = 'From: '.$bn.' <'.$rencDiv['admin_email'].'>';
                    $he[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    $s = '<html><head></head><body>'.$s.'</body></html>';
                }
                @wp_mail($r->user_email, $bn." - ".__('Happy Birthday','rencontre'), $s, $he);
                ++$cm;
                $s1 .= $s;
            }
        }
        // 12. Efface une fois par semaine les statistiques du nombre de mail par heure
        if(current_time("N")=="1") { // le lundi
            $t=@fopen($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cronListe.txt','w'); @fwrite($t,'0'); @fclose($t);
            $t=@fopen($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cron.txt','w'); @fwrite($t,$cm); @fclose($t);
        }
    }
    // 13. Mail vers les membres et nettoyage des comptes actions (suppression comptes inexistants)
    $hcron = (isset($rencOpt['hcron'])?$rencOpt['hcron']+0:3);
    $j = floor((floor((time()-3600*$hcron)/86400)/60 - floor(floor((time()-3600*$hcron)/86400)/60)) * 60 +.00001); // horloge de jour de 0 à 59 (temps unix) - ex : aujourd'hui -> 4 ; ajout de hcron pour rester le meme jour dans la plage +12h
    if(isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==2) {
        $j0 = floor(($j/15-floor($j/15)) * 15 + .00001); // horloge de jour de 0 a 14
        if(!$cronBis) { // CRON (H)
            $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.85)); // 85% du max - heure creuse - 15% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres et anniv
            $j1=$j0+15;
        }
        else { // CRON BIS (H+1)
            $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.95)); // 95% du max - heure creuse - 5% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres
            $j2=$j0+30; $j3=$j0+45;
        }
    }
    else if(isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==3) {
        $j0 = floor(($j/7-floor($j/7)) * 7 + .00001); // horloge de jour de 0 a 6
        if(!$cronBis) { // CRON (H)
            $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.85)); // 85% du max - heure creuse - 15% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres et anniv
            $j1=$j0+7; $j2=$j0+14; $j3=$j0+21;
        }
        else { // CRON BIS (H+1)
            $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.95)); // 95% du max - heure creuse - 5% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres
            $j4=$j0+28; $j5=$j0+35; $j6=$j0+42; $j7=$j0+49; $j8=$j0+56;
        }
    }
    else { // ($max needed)
        $jj = ($j>29)?$j-30:$j+30; // aujourd'hui : 34
        if(!$cronBis) $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.85)); // 85% du max - heure creuse - 15% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres et anniv
        else $max = floor(max(0, (isset($rencOpt['qmail'])?$rencOpt['qmail']:0)*.95)); // 95% du max - heure creuse - 5% restant pour inscription nouveaux membres
    }
        // 13.1 selection des membres
    $rencDrap = array();
    if(!isset($rencCustom['place'])) {
        $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT
                c_liste_categ,
                c_liste_valeur,
                c_liste_iso 
            FROM
                ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_liste 
            WHERE 
                c_liste_categ='d' or (c_liste_categ='p' and c_liste_lang='".substr($rencDiv['lang'],0,2)."')
            ");
        foreach($q as $r) {
            if($r->c_liste_categ=='d') $rencDrap[$r->c_liste_iso] = $r->c_liste_valeur;
        }
    }
    $q=0;
    $qq1 = "SELECT 
            U.ID,
            U.user_login,
            U.user_email,
            P.t_action,
            R.c_pays,
            R.i_sex,
            R.i_zsex,
            R.c_zsex,
            R.i_zage_min,
            R.i_zage_max,
            R.i_zrelation,
            R.c_zrelation
        FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
        INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
            ON R.user_id=U.ID
        INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users_profil P
            ON P.user_id=U.ID ";
    $qq2 = " and R.i_sex!='98'
            and R.i_status!=4
            and (P.t_action NOT LIKE '%,nomail,%' or P.t_action IS NULL)
        ORDER BY P.d_modif DESC
        LIMIT ".$max;
    if(!$cronBis && isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==2) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered) IN (".$j0.",".$j1.") ".$qq2);
    else if($cronBis && isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==2) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered) IN (".$j2.",".$j3.") ".$qq2);
    else if(!$cronBis && isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==3) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered) IN (".$j0.",".$j1.",".$j2.",".$j3.") ".$qq2);
    else if($cronBis && isset($rencOpt['mailmois'])  && $rencOpt['mailmois']==3) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered) IN (".$j4.",".$j5.",".$j6.",".$j7.",".$j8.") ".$qq2);
    else if(!$cronBis) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered)='".$j."' ".$qq2);
    else if($cronBis) $q = $wpdb->get_results($qq1." WHERE SECOND(U.user_registered)='".$jj."' ".$qq2);
    if(isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==1) $ti = 2592000; // 30j
    else if(isset($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $rencOpt['mailmois']==2) $ti = 1296000; // 15j
    else $ti = 604800; // 7j
    
        // 13.2 boucle de mail
    $ct=0;
    if($q) foreach($q as $r) {
        ++$ct;
        $melCountry = (!empty($rencOpt['melctry'])&&!empty($r->c_pays)&&empty($rencCustom['country'])&&empty($rencCustom['place'])?"and R.c_pays='".$r->c_pays."'":"");
        $action = json_decode($r->t_action,true);
        if(!empty($rencOpt['mailmois']) && $ct<=$max) {
            $b = 0;
            // Connect_link
            if(function_exists('openssl_encrypt')) $oo = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($r->ID.'|'.$r->user_login.'|'.time(), 'AES-256-CBC', substr(AUTH_KEY,0,32), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
            // BONJOUR
            $s = "<div style='font-family:\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica;font-size:13px;text-align:left;margin:5px 5px 5px 10px;'>".__('Hello','rencontre')."&nbsp;".$r->user_login.",";
            if(!empty($rencOpt['textmail']) && strlen($rencOpt['textmail'])>10) $s .= "<br />".nl2br(stripslashes($rencOpt['textmail']))."\n";
            // NBR VISITES
            if(isset($action['visite'])) $s .= "<p style='font-weight:700;font-size:.9em;'>".__('Your profile has been visited','rencontre')."&nbsp;<span style='color:red;'>".count($action['visite'])."&nbsp;".__('time','rencontre')."</span>.\n</p>";
            // PROPOSITIONS
            $zmin=date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")-$r->i_zage_min));
            $zmax=date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")-$r->i_zage_max));
            // Selection par le sex
            if($r->i_sex==$r->i_zsex) $homo=1; else $homo=0;
            if($r->i_zsex!=99) {
                $sexQuery = " and R.i_sex=".$r->i_zsex." ";
                if(!isset($rencCustom['sex'])) $sexQuery .= " and R.i_zsex".(($homo)?'='.$r->i_zsex:'!='.$r->i_zsex)." ";
            }
            else $sexQuery = " and R.i_sex IN (".substr($r->c_zsex,1,-1).") ";
            if($r->i_zrelation!=99) $relQuery = " and (R.i_zrelation=".$r->i_zrelation." or  R.c_zrelation LIKE '%,".$r->i_zrelation.",%') ";
            else $relQuery = ''; // pas de else - trop complique sans boucle - ,1,3,6, IN/LIKE/= ,2,3,5,
            //
            $q1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
                    U.ID, 
                    U.user_login, 
                    R.d_naissance, 
                    R.c_pays, 
                    R.c_ville, 
                    P.t_titre
                FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                    ON R.user_id=U.ID
                INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users_profil P
                    ON P.user_id=U.ID
                WHERE 
                    U.ID!='".$r->ID."'
                    ".$sexQuery."
                    ".$relQuery."
                    and R.d_naissance<'".$zmin."' 
                    and R.d_naissance>'".$zmax."' 
                    ".((!empty($rencOpt['onlyphoto']) || !empty($rencOpt['mailph']))?" and R.i_photo>0 ":" ")."
                    ".$melCountry."
                ORDER BY U.user_registered DESC
                LIMIT ".(!empty($rencOpt['nbr']['mailSelection'])?$rencOpt['nbr']['mailSelection']:4));
            if($q1) {
                $b = 1;
                $s .= "<p style='font-weight:700;font-size:.9em;'>".__('Here\'s a selection of members that may interest you','rencontre')." :</p>";
                $s .= "<table><tr>";
                $c = 0;
                foreach($q1 as $r1) {
                    ++$c;
                    $s .= "<td>".rencMailBox($r1,$rencDrap,$oo,$ii)."</td>"."\n";
                    if($c>$mailPerline)
                        {
                        $c = 0;
                        $s .= "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>";
                    }
                }
                $s .= "</tr></table>"."\n";
                }
            // SOURIRES
            if(isset($action['sourireIn']) && count($action['sourireIn'])) {
                $t = "<p style='font-weight:700;font-size:.9em;'>";
                if(isset($rencCustom['smiw']) && isset($rencCustom['smiw4']) && $rencCustom['smiw'] && $rencCustom['smiw4']) $t .= stripslashes($rencCustom['smiw4']);
                else $t .= __('You have received a smile from','rencontre');
                $t .= " :\n</p><table><tr>";
                $c = 0;
                for($v=0; $v<count($action['sourireIn']);++$v) {
                    if(isset($action['contactIn'][$v]['d']) && strtotime($action['contactIn'][$v]['d'])>current_time('timestamp',0)-$ti) { // only new before last mail
                        $r1 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT
                                U.ID,
                                U.user_login,
                                R.d_naissance,
                                R.c_pays,
                                R.c_ville,
                                P.t_titre
                            FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                                ON R.user_id=U.ID
                            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users_profil P
                                ON P.user_id=U.ID
                            WHERE 
                                R.user_id='".$action['sourireIn'][$v]['i']."'
                                ".((!empty($rencOpt['onlyphoto']) || !empty($rencOpt['mailph']))?" and R.i_photo>0 ":" ")."
                                ".$melCountry."
                            ORDER BY R.d_session DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                            ");
                        if($r1) {
                            $b = 1;
                            ++$c;
                            $s .= $t."<td>".rencMailBox($r1,$rencDrap,$oo,$ii)."</td>"."\n";
                            $t = '';
                            if($c>$mailPerline) {
                                $c = 0;
                                $s .= "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($t=="") $s .= "</tr></table>"."\n";
            }
            // DEMANDES DE CONTACT
            if(isset($action['contactIn']) && count($action['contactIn'])) {
                $t = "<p style='font-weight:700;font-size:.9em;'>".__('You have received a contact request from','rencontre')." :\n</p><table><tr>";
                $c = 0;
                for ($v=0; $v<count($action['contactIn']);++$v) {
                    if(isset($action['contactIn'][$v]['d']) && strtotime($action['contactIn'][$v]['d'])>current_time('timestamp',0)-$ti) { // only new before last mail
                        $r1 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT
                                U.ID,
                                U.user_login,
                                R.d_naissance,
                                R.c_pays,
                                R.c_ville,
                                P.t_titre
                            FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users U
                            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users R
                                ON R.user_id=U.ID
                            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users_profil P
                                ON P.user_id=U.ID
                            WHERE 
                                R.user_id='".$action['contactIn'][$v]['i']."'
                                ".((!empty($rencOpt['onlyphoto']) || !empty($rencOpt['mailph']))?" and R.i_photo>0 ":" ")."
                                ".$melCountry."
                            ORDER BY R.d_session DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                            ");
                        if($r1) {
                            ++$c;
                            $s .= $t."<td>".rencMailBox($r1,$rencDrap,$oo,$ii)."</td>"."\n";
                            $t = '';
                            if($c>$mailPerline) {
                                $b = 1;
                                $c = 0;
                                $s .= "</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($t=="") $s .= "</tr></table>";
            }
            // MESSAGES
            $n = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_msg M WHERE M.recipient='".$r->user_login."' and M.read=0 and M.deleted=0");
            if($n) {
                $b = 1;
                $s .= "<p style='font-weight:700;font-size:.9em;'>".__('You have','rencontre')."&nbsp;<span style='color:red;'>".$n."&nbsp;".(($n>1)?__('messages','rencontre'):__('message','rencontre'))."</span>&nbsp;".__('in your inbox.','rencontre')."\n</p>";
            }
            // MOT DE LA FIN
            $s .= "<p>".__("Do not hesitate to send us your comments.",'rencontre')."\n</p><br />".__('Regards,','rencontre')."<br />".$bn;
            if($b) {
                $buttonCSS = "color:".$w3renc[$bt0.'T'].";background-color:".$w3renc[$bt0].";border:none;display:inline-block;width:45%;padding:8px 16px;vertical-align:middle;overflow:hidden;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;font-size:11px;letter-spacing:-.5px";
                $buttonHover = "this.style.backgroundColor='".$w3renc[$bt1]."';this.style.color='".$w3renc[$bt1.'T']."'";
                $buttonOut = "this.style.backgroundColor='".$w3renc[$bt0]."';this.style.color='".$w3renc[$bt0.'T']."'";
                $s .= "<div style='margin:8px 0 0;text-align:center;'><a style='".$buttonCSS."' onMouseOver='".$buttonHover."' onMouseOut='".$buttonOut."' href='".htmlspecialchars((empty($rencOpt['home'])?site_url():$rencOpt['home'])."?".$Loo."=".urlencode($oo)."&".$Lii."=".urlencode($ii))."' target='_blank'> ".__('Login','rencontre')."\n</a></div>";
            }
            $s .= "</div>";
            //
            $s1 .= $s;
            if($b) {
                $he = array();
                if(!empty($rencOpt['mailfo']) || !has_filter('wp_mail_content_type')) {
                    $he[] = 'From: '.$bn.' <'.$rencDiv['admin_email'].'>';
                    $he[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
                    $s = '<html><head></head><body>'.$s.'</body></html>';
                }
                @wp_mail($r->user_email, $bn, $s, $he);
                ++$cm;
            }
            if(file_exists($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/cron_liste/'.$r->ID.'.txt')) @unlink($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/cron_liste/'.$r->ID.'.txt');
        }
        // 13.3 *********** Nettoyage des comptes action *********
        // {"sourireIn":[{"i":992,"d":"2015-09-01"},{"i":75,"d":"2015-09-01"}],"contactIn":[{"i":992,"d":"2015-09-01"}]}
        $ac = array("sourireIn","sourireOut","contactIn","contactOut","visite","bloque");
        $x = 0;
        for($v=0; $v<count($ac); ++$v) {
            if(isset($action[$ac[$v]])) {
                $c = count($action[$ac[$v]]);
                for($w=0; $w<$c; ++$w) {
                    if(isset($action[$ac[$v]][$w]['i'])) {
                        $q1 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id 
                            FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_users 
                            WHERE user_id='".$action[$ac[$v]][$w]['i']."'
                            LIMIT 1"); // compte suprime ?
                        if(!$q1) {
                            if(!$x) $x = 1;
                            unset($action[$ac[$v]][$w]['i']); 
                            unset($action[$ac[$v]][$w]['d']);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($action[$ac[$v]]) $action[$ac[$v]] = array_filter($action[$ac[$v]]);
                if($action[$ac[$v]]) $action[$ac[$v]] = array_splice($action[$ac[$v]], 0); // remise en ordre avec de nouvelles clefs
            }
        }
        if($x) {
            $out = json_encode($action);
            $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'rencontre_users_profil', array('t_action'=>$out), array('user_id'=>$r->ID));
        }
        // 14. Suppression des msg anciens
        if(!empty($rencOpt['msgdel'])) {
            $d = array(1=>7884000, 2=>15768000, 3=>31536000, 4=>2592000);
            if(isset($d[$rencOpt['msgdel']])) {
                $d1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()-$d[$rencOpt['msgdel']]);
                $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."rencontre_msg WHERE date<'".$d1."' ");
            }
        }
        // ***************************************************
    }
    // 15. Premium Cron
    $ho = false; if(has_filter('rencCronP', 'f_rencCronP')) $ho = apply_filters('rencCronP', $ho);
    //
    if(current_time("N")!="1")$t=@fopen($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cron.txt', 'w'); @fwrite($t,max((file_get_contents($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cron.txt')+0),$cm)); @fclose($t);
    if($cronBis) @unlink($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cronBis.txt'); // CRON BIS effectue
    else {$t=@fopen($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cronBis.txt', 'w'); @fclose($t);} // CRON BIS a faire
    @unlink($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cronOn.txt');
    @unlink($rencDiv['basedir'].'/portrait/cache/rencontre_cronListeOn.txt');
    clearstatcache();
}
```

Comment: The problem here may be that you're unaware of variable scope, or the order code runs, but it's impossible to tell without knowing more about what `$value` is meant to be and where you're getting it from. That variable has to come from somewhere, so provide some context, as well as what the problem you're trying to debug is. At the moment there isn't enough information to understand your problem, so use the edit link under the tags to update your question

Comment: 0

Not an answer, but my head spins looking at the code and trying to debug it with var_dump().

Consider using xdebug to really be able to debug things clearly, otherwise it will take you forever to find find/fix bugs:

https://www.codeforest.net/debug-wordpress-with-xdebug